# How can eliminate an specific element in array asocc using element position [2]

Tags: php

How can we eliminate an specific element in array asocc using an specific  position instead of key or value. thanks like: i want to remove my 3rd Positions array.if i dont know its key or value.

```
[  
 {
   item_number: "1",
   total: 1,
   OptionName: "12 Inches",
   ItemExtraName: null
 },
 {
  item_number: "4",
  total: 3,
  OptionName: "12 Inches",
  ItemExtraName: null
 },
 {
  item_number: "4",
  total: 1,
  OptionName: "14 Inches",
  ItemExtraName: [
   "Extra Mushroom",
   "Extra Pepperoni"
   ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Please post your code. what have you tried ??

Comment: function   remove ($item){    //remove this item from the array asoc   }

Answer (score 1):

use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). For example:

```
unset($array[2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you but, dosnt  work

```
public function remove($element) {
    $productos = Session()->get('prod');


    unset($productos[$element]);         
    return redirect('/showcarrito');
}
```

Comment: need more information. Where's the `Session()` class come from? Does it have a put() method? If so, try doing something like `put('prod', $productos)` after unsetting from the $productos array. From the looks of it, you're unsetting element from the array but not updating it in the session.